# How to use PowerShell deployment scripts under TFVC in Release Definitions

Tags: tfs, release-management

I am maintaining my deployment PowerShell script under TFVC. I would like to use/reference these scripts in my Release Definition PowerShell steps. What is the best way to do this?

I am on TFS 2017 Update 1 (on-prem).

Comment: You could use create a build definition to publish the script files as build artifacts and link this build definition in your release definition. Or you create a changeset that contain these script file, in release artifact source type, choose TFVC. When create release, choose this change set.

Comment: Why he should create a changeset? That’s not maintainable and if I remember it is without scripting not possible to access ChangeSets from RM. The deployment and configuration scripts also different from version to version. My suggestion keep calm and check in your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment scripts are a part of the project and you should pick the deployments from the same version like your sources.

If you have multiple branches and versions (Feature, Master and Release) you have to manage different versions of deployment scripts.

> I attached a screenshot to show which tasks a build process should do
>   and what are typical task are of a release management system.

[image]

> The purpose of the build process is: (Continuous Integration CI)

- Build your application
- Static code analysis
- Running unit tests (CI)
- Versioning your sources
- Package your artifacts (binaries +  deployment + dependencies)

> The purpose of Release Management is: (Continuous- Delivery or
>   Deployment CD)

- Creating and configure test pipelines
- Manage environment configuration
- Configure and deploying environment
- Creating and managing Container
- Run system und functional tests
- Run load and performance test

> I manage my deployment scripts in a PowerShell project in the project
>   solution.  You have to install the PowerShell extension in Visual Studio. After that you can create a PowerShell project.

In the TFS build system you can pick and copy your deployment files.

> You can use the step "Copy Files" with this configuration:

```
Source Folder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyPowerShellProject.pssproj
Content: *.ps1
Target Folder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\DeploymentScripts
```

> After that with the step "Publish Artifacts" you can publish the
>   artifacts from

```
 $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\DeploymentScripts
```

> into the TFS or on a fileshare.

Now release management will automatically download your artifats as the first step of your release definition.

If you think, thats nice to know give me a vote.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a dumb Build that pulls the script and publish them as Artifacts.
Your Release can pick these Artifacts in addition to the principal Build Artifacts.

For an example of dummy build, you can see my post [*Mixing TFVC and Git*](http://blog.casavian.eu/2017/03/04/mixing-tfvc-and-git/).